# $(\dots, X_{t-1}, X_t)$ and $(X_{t+1}, X_{t+2}, \dots) $ are independent $\Rightarrow (X_t)$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, time-series

In some lecture notes in Time Series Analysis it was written:
If the random vectors $(\dots, X_{t-1}, X_t)$ and $(X_{t+1}, X_{t+2}, \dots)$ are independent for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$, then it is obvious that the random variables $X_t$ are independent. I am not sure how is this obvious. It seems true but I can not find a way to prove it. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: Start by showing that $X_t$ and $X_s$ are independent, for every $t\ne s$.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I tried to do, but I did not find a way to go from the independents between the vectors to independents between random variables in the vectors. :(

Comment: In case you are still interested, the accepted answer shows (following my hint) how to prove that $(X_t)$ is pairwise independent (even the last sentence is about pairwise independence). This does not prove the independence, that your question asked to show.

Comment: So I need to consider events, meaning working on independence of $X_t$ to any subset of $\sigma(\dots, X_{t-1}, X_{t+1}, \dots)$?

Comment: Tell me... $ $ $ $

Comment: I will work on it and see where I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are independent and $f$ and $g$ are (measurable) functions
then $f\left(X\right)$ and $g\left(Y\right)$ are independent.

Here define $f$ by $\left(\dots,X_{t-1},X_{t}\right)\mapsto X_{t}$
and $g$ by $\left(X_{t+1},X_{t+2},\ldots\right)\mapsto X_{t+1}$.

Likewise you can prove more generally that $X_t$ and $X_{t+k}$ are independent for $k>1$.

Comment: Ok, but why are $f,g$, defined above, measurable? Is this obvious?

Comment: Yes. Projections like $\left(\dots,a\right)\mapsto a$ are
measurable.

Comment: Thanks. Can you refer me to somewhere I can see a prove of the measurable functions of independent variables are independent?

Comment: Maybe this will do: $P\left\{ f\left(X\right)\in A\wedge g\left(Y\right)\in B\right\} =P\left\{ X\in f^{-1}\left(A\right)\wedge Y\in g^{-1}\left(B\right)\right\} =P\left\{ X\in f^{-1}\left(A\right)\right\} \times P\left\{ Y\in g^{-1}\left(B\right)\right\} =P\left\{ f\left(X\right)\in A\right\} \times P\left\{ g\left(Y\right)\in B\right\} $